# Setting a custom header using BrowserMob-Proxy REST api

Tags: java, selenium, proxy, webdriver, browsermob

I have a browsermob proxy running on port 9091. I am trying to use browsermob-proxy REST API to set a custom header. When I make a request to my app using Selenium via the proxy, I don't see the header printed in my apps console. Below is my code. The request body is based on documentation [here](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy#http-request-manipulation). My requirement is to use BrowserMob proxy API and not its Java library for this particular use case. Anything I am doing wrong in the code below?

```
 Proxy proxy = new java.net.Proxy(java.net.Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 9091));

 String bpmUrl = "http://localhost:8787/proxy/9091/interceptor/request";
 Client client = Client.create();
 String requestBody = "request.getMethod().addHeader(\"custom-header\", \"Bananabot/1.0\");";
 WebResource resource = client.resource(bpmUrl);
 resource.type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE).post(requestBody);

 String url = "http://localhost:8004";
 DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
 capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
 driver.get(url);
 driver.quit();
```

**Edit 1**

I tried @Erki's solution which I think should work, but its not. Anything missing here?

```
 String bpmUrl = "http://localhost:8787/proxy/9091/headers";
     Map<String,String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
     data.put("user-agent","Bananabot");
     ClientConfig cc = new DefaultClientConfig();
     cc.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);
     Client client = Client.create(cc);
     WebResource resource = client.resource(bpmUrl);
     resource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(ClientResponse.class, data);
```

**Edit 2**
Found the answer, I tried Java API, it worked and noticed that the browser is using proxy as expected. With my code above, obviously the browser was not using proxy. So instead of using `java.net.Proxy` I used `org.openqa.selenium.Proxy` which worked. So the only code change I needed was the way I initialize the proxy, rest of it is same. This works fine now.

```
 String PROXY = "localhost:9091";
 Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
 proxy.setHttpProxy(PROXY);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the code that corresponds to using the BMP in embedded mode:

```
server.addRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {
    @Override
    public void process(BrowserMobHttpRequest request, Har har) {
        request.getMethod().removeHeaders("User-Agent");
        request.getMethod().addHeader("User-Agent", "Bananabot/1.0");
    }
});
```

This code would do if you had actually started the proxy server in embedded mode, which, as far as I understand, is not what you have done or have intended to. What you need is probably:

> POST /proxy/[port]/headers - Set and override HTTP Request headers.
>   For example setting a custom User-Agent. Payload data should be json
>   encoded set of headers (not url-encoded)

Comment: +1, I think you are right. I tried the POST you mentioned above but its still not working. I updated my attempt in question. Thanks!