# Proxy server for Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, proxy

I'm trying to use a proxy server to launch the Selenium Chrome driver. The only solution so far that I found was to use a sort of plugin for Chrome to authenticate, but it's not very reliable, so I was wondering if there is any other option.

Here is what I use now

```
    manifest_json = """
    {
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Chrome Proxy",
    "permissions": [
    "proxy",
    "tabs",
    "unlimitedStorage",
    "storage",
    "<all_urls>",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking"
    ],
    "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "minimum_chrome_version":"22.0.0"
    }
    """

background_js = """
    var config = {
    mode: "fixed_servers",
    rules: {
    singleProxy: {
    scheme: "http",
    host: "",
    port: parseInt(6060)
    },
    bypassList: ["foobar.com"]
    }
    };

    chrome.proxy.settings.set({value: config, scope: "regular"}, function() {});

    function callbackFn(details) {
    return {
    authCredentials: {
    username: "",
    password: ""
    }
    };
    }

    chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
    callbackFn,
    {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
    ['blocking']
    );
    """


pluginfile = 'proxy_auth_plugin.zip'

with zipfile.ZipFile(pluginfile, 'w') as zp:
    zp.writestr("manifest.json", manifest_json)
    zp.writestr("background.js", background_js)

co = Options()
co.add_argument("--start-maximized")
co.add_extension(pluginfile)


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think plugins are a very good solution, certainly not when there are pure HTTP solutions that work the same across all browsers, versions, and operating systems.

You could use this [Python wrapper](https://github.com/AutomatedTester/browsermob-proxy-py) for [Browsermob](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy), which is a very well-known standalone or embedded proxy server written in Java.

The [code](https://github.com/AutomatedTester/browsermob-proxy-py/blob/master/browsermobproxy/client.py#L181) shows how the `headers()` Python method can be used to add headers, without the need to POST to the REST API. The tests have [some examples](https://github.com/AutomatedTester/browsermob-proxy-py/blob/master/test/test_client.py) of it in use, e.g.:

```
self.client = Client("localhost:9090")
self.client.headers({'User-Agent': 'rubber ducks floating in a row'})
self.client.headers({'Authorization': 'Basic dXNlcjpwYXNz'})  # User 'user', password 'pass'
```

**Update:**

Just to clarify how the WebDriver and the proxy fit together:

- Start your proxy server first, and wait until it's ready. You can do that externally and pass host:port to WebDriver, or start it embedded in your application then pass WebDriver a `proxy` object.
- [This example](https://github.com/AutomatedTester/browsermob-proxy-py#how-to-use-with-selenium-webdriver) demonstrates the second approach, using Firefox profiles and Chrome options.
- Alternatively, start the proxy embedded, use it to obtain a `Proxy` object, which represents a Selenium proxy server, then add it to your `DesiredCapabilities` object, and create your driver that way, as per [this example](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy#using-with-selenium).

From that point on, the proxy-listening is automatic, and you can start to create your HAR files.

---

Alternatively, you could see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9469400/954442) for a custom Python proxy server using Twisted.

I have a longer answer about Selenium proxies in Python [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35004026/954442).

Comment: Sorry, I missed out the link. Fixed in the answer now. https://github.com/AutomatedTester/browsermob-proxy-py

Comment: thx again. So this is the code for Chrome for example from   `browsermobproxy import Server
server = Server("path/to/browsermob-proxy")
server.start()
proxy = server.create_proxy()  chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--proxy-server={0}".format(proxy.proxy))
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = chrome_options)`

Comment: does it also let you use a username and password?  Thanks

Comment: Only time for a quick answer, but if you mean using a user/pass for basic authentication dialogs, yes. I cover that here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35004026/954442

Comment: thanks.  Trying to figure out now how to implement that POST call in Python.

Comment: Actually you don't need to use the REST API at all. I've updated my answer with an example of the Python `headers()` method.

Comment: thank you once again. So basically now I just need to figure out how to pass basic auth - server, pass and username - through headers.

Comment: One more edit ^^ Just Base64 '<user>:<pass>' , prefix with 'Basic '. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Client_side, see also: https://www.base64encode.org/