# How to handle authentication required pop up in next tab in selenium webdriver using java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

In Chrome, clicking a certain link opens a new tab with an "Authentication Required" popup. As you can see, it has 'User name' and 'password' with 'Log In' and 'Cancel' buttons.

With Java code, how can I enter values (user name and password) in this popup? Because I can't get the locator of username and password, also the alert method is not working here.

[image]

The code I tried:

```
public static void switchToalert() {
    driver.switchTo().alert();
    // Selenium-WebDriver Java Code for entering Username & Password as // below: 
    driver.findElement(By.id("Username")).sendKeys("userName");
    driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys("myPassword");
    driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
}
```

Thanks
Govind

Comment: @Mr.Hyde Plz find the code

Comment: @Govid Will you post html of new open window here. Or it is browser authentication alert. Please confirm these things so may b i can help you further.

Comment: @Govind please post html of new window or add picture of new window and alert.

Comment: @MuhammadUSman..Its Browser authentication alert...so i am not able to find the locator also...so its difficult to enter the value for username and password.

Comment: @MuhammadUSman attached the image on top

"enter image description here"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handle Windows Authentication using Selenium Webdriver

### You can provide credentials in URL itself it means we will add username and password in URL so while running script it will bypass the same

```
http://username:password@yourWebURL
##example##

http:
//GuravPraveen:Passwrd123@YourURL


driver.get("http://GuravPraveen:Passwrd123@www.xyz.com/signin");
```

Comment: This is amazing, we've been trying to work around authentication for so long and the answer is so simple! Thanks

Comment: @SteveWeaverCrawford just for the info: that won't work in the newest Chrome (M59) and Opera.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I've used very successfully is to set up an embedded [Browsermob](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy) proxy server (in Java code) and register a `RequestInterceptor` to intercept all incoming requests (that match the host / URL pattern in question).

When you have a request that would otherwise need Basic auth, [add an](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25596166/954442) `Authorization` HTTP header with the credentials required ('Basic ' + the Base64-encoded 'user:pass' string. So for 'foo:bar' you'd set the value `Basic Zm9vOmJhcg==`)

Start the server, set it as a web proxy [for Selenium traffic](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy#using-with-selenium), and when a request is made that requires authentication, the proxy will add the header, the browser will see it, verify the credentials, and not need to pop up the dialog.

You won't need to deal with the dialog at all. Another benefit is that because it's a pure HTTP solution, it works the same across all browsers and operating systems.